# Can`t run existing Django project

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I downloaded python 3.7 and django framework. 
There is an existing project I want to run and execute. I've added python interpreter, there wasn't any errors and then I tried to run it and... as ypu can see there are a lot of errors. I don't know the reason and a way to solve that problem

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader

Exception in thread django-main-thread:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()

  File "C:\Python\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)

  File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'social_django'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/skantorp/Documents/Univer/Task02/SSPLS/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 577, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 562, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 280, in run
    self.run_loop()

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 286, in run_loop
    next(ticker)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 326, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 342, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 241, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 128, in iter_modules_and_files
    if not path.exists():

  File "C:\Python\lib\pathlib.py", line 1319, in exists
    self.stat()

  File "C:\Python\lib\pathlib.py", line 1139, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)

  File "C:\Python\lib\pathlib.py", line 390, in wrapped
    return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anyone have any ideas? If you do please let me know. Any help appreciates

Comment: first of all, does the project have a pip *requirements.txt* file? That should list all the necessary packages. `pip install -r requirements.txt` would install them in your virtual environment. Second, was the project written in python 3.x? Or in python 2.x? That's important, since if you deal with an old project written in python 2.x, it might not be compatible with python 3.x

Comment: i installed python 2.x and there is less amount of errors

Comment: unfortunately, there is not file requirements.txt file. How i can fix it?

Comment: There must be a file with the list of dependencies. No other way. Maybe it’s not called *requirements.txt*. Should be in the root of the project somewhere. Otherwise ask the person that wrote the project.